# Laravel 4.2 Auth::attempt failure

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

**Problem:** returns false every time i try to Auth::attempt()

**myUsersModel.php**

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class myUsersModel extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface{

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

protected $table = 'myUsersTable';
protected $primaryKey = 'primary_key';
public $timestamps = false;
protected $increments = 'primary_key';
protected $fillable = array(
   'user',           //this is like username
   'password',       //this one contains hashed password values
   'userlevel',
   'remember_token',
);
   protected $hidden = array('password');
}
```

**myController.php**

```
$attemptData = array(
    'user' => Input::get('textBoxInput'),
    'password' => Input::get('passwordInput')
);
Auth::attempt($attemptData);
return var_dump(Auth::check());
```

**auth.php**

```
'driver' => 'eloquent',
'model' => 'myUsersModel',
'table' => 'myUsersTable'
```

Another notes :
1. My remember token is nullable `varchar(100)`
2. My password field is `varchar(60)`
3. I can get form values with `dd(Input:all())`
4. In my database, i have both hashed and non-hashed password values, different for each user. But both cannot log in.

Thanks.

Comment: is the $primaryKey the 'id', because by default laravel assumes the 'id' to be the user identifier.

Comment: @yangqi, yes it is. I solved the problem, now i'll share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't posted my entire customized model and controller, but my model has an email field like `'user_e_mail'` and to meet the requirements of my authentication rules, which needs to be checked.
Here's the thing, i had to override `getReminderEmail()` method under `myUsersModel` model.

```
public function getReminderEmail() {
    return $this->user_e_mail;
}
```

So now i am able to authenticate.

Thanks.